# How can I create h:selectOneRadio with options of a java list (JSF)?

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, radio-button

I would like a JSF menu with h:selectOneRadio and information of Java ArrayList.
This is my code:

XHTML:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.element}">
    <ui:repeat value = "#{bean.items}" var = "i">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{bean.elements[i]}" itemLabel="#{bean.elements[i]}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Bean:

```
package bean.controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {

    private String element;
    private ArrayList<Integer> items;
    private ArrayList<String> elements;

    public Bean() {
        element = "hello";
        elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        elements.add("world");
        elements.add("hello");
        elements.add("thanks");
        items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        items.add(1);
        items.add(2);
        items.add(3);
    }


    public void load() throws IOException {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("link.xhtml");
    }

    public void listenerFuncion() {
        System.out.println("Listener");
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(ArrayList<String> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

The XHTML is empty, I don't see any item. I would like load all list and with a click on any selectItem, the `element` variable change its value.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `ui:repeat` and `f:selectItem`, use [`f:selectItems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html), which can take a list of items.

Here is an example for your situation:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.element}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" var="i" itemValue="#{bean.elements[i]}" itemLabel="#{bean.elements[i]}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I'm not sure I fully understand the contents of the variables you are using, but this may also work better for you:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.element}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.elements}" var="i" itemValue="#{i}" itemLabel="#{i}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Perfect! Beautiful!! THANKS!

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes, in one minute xD

Comment: Can you say me how I can add "<br/>" for each item?

Comment: @JuanCamiloCamachoBeltrán On `h:selectOneRadio`, add `layout="pageDirection"`

Comment: Yeah! again this is perfect!